# Comparing Geo Location points in Java

Tags: java, geolocation

Say I have a `GeoPoint` class, how do I implement a Comparable compareTo method with such Geo Location:

```java
public class GeoPoint implements Comparable<GeoPoint>, Serializable {

  private Double longitude;
  private Double latitude;

  public GeoPoint(Double longitude, Double latitude) {
    setLongitude(longitude);
    setLatitude(latitude);
  }

  @Override public int compareTo(@NotNull GeoPoint geoPoint) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you want to compare them? distance based on km or something else?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question of implementing a `compareTo()`, it is more of about how to calculated distance between two points. That said, `compareTo()` provides natural ordering, so you should first think about how to get this done. AFAIK, distance is always positive and a distance from one point to another is always equal(*x->y* equals *y->x*). So, for instance you may want to know if a car is going forward or backward based on the location points you get. How do you compare the second point with regard to the initial point, since the earth is spherical.

I don't think you can naturally order a point with lat and long only. Check the following if it helps.https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html